# How to prevent addValueEventListener of one activity being called in another activity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two activities, say ActivityOne.java and ActivityTwo.java. I am navigating from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo with a condition as follows..

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(UserDetails.username).child("isPlaying");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        if(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("false")){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityOne.this,ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(ActivityOne.this,"You cannot play now",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Initially the value returned will be false and the ActivityTwo.java will be started. Now in ActivityTwo.java, i am making a change at the same node with which changes it's value to 'true'.

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(NumberGuess.this);
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();

    String url = "https://couplegoals-80d0f.firebaseio.com/users.json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {

            Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://couplegoals-80d0f.firebaseio.com/users");
            reference.child(UserDetails.username).child("isPlaying").setValue("true");
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NumberGuess.this);
    rQueue.add(request);
```

This again calls the addValueEventListener in the ActivityOne.java and displays the toast "Sorry, you cannot play now", which does not need to happen. How it is getting called when i am in another activity? How can i resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read the value only once, and then just process the result. In that case you'll want to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

All the rest of your code can stay the same.

Using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` means that Firebase immediately removes the listener after it has fired `onDataChange`. So it's similar to Deep's answer, but removes the listener sooner and implicitly.

Comment: best and more simple solution

Answer (score 2):

**On Changing Activity from `ActivityOne` to `ActivityTwo`, try putting code for removing the listener.**

> You can remove the listener from within the callback with this code in your `ActivityOne`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ref.removeEventListener(this); //ref will be your node where you are setting Event Listener.
    }
```